# Is there a way to set the badge value from my app instead of getting it from the server ?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm working with push notifications on a device.

Is there a way to set the badge value from my app instead of getting it from the server ?

I'm referring to the case when the app is in background, (and the system popups an alert dialog). I'm not storing the badge value on the server, but locally in my app.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find such possibility. It is very strange that Apple didn't provide such obvious mechanism. Autobadging using your own webserver is the one possible way to set appropriate badge value. Because of this I'm not sending that value through push-notification.

The only approach is to set it when your application becomes active.

Comment: Shit.. ya but if the user closes the alert instead of viewing it, there is no way to set it... or am I wrong?

Comment: I didn't find the solution... This is why such services as urban ship provide autobadge functionality.

Comment: No, you can set it, but only the value that you provided in push-notification.

Comment: Ya but it is totally useless, since it can't be stored in the sender. I have to implement additional code in the backend... or I can disable the close button ? But I guess wit ios5 the alerts will be closed automatically after a while

Comment: You can only change title of view button.